# What's the general way to solve worker/time/job problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem says "In a factory, m workers work h hours to do j jobs. If p new workers are hired, how many hours will the work force have to work to do j jobs?" I worked out the answer logically, but I'd like to know if there's a formula that I can go to to make it simpler and faster when this kind of question arises again. Also I'm really not sure what the type of problem is called, so sorry for any confusion in tagging/titling.

Comment: Increasing [m], the number of workers (for the job) will take less time [h] to finish it. Thus, m and h are inversely proportional. Mathematically, we represent this fact by saying m.h = constant. In view of this, solving such kind of problem, we are better off by creating a new unit called man-hour.

Answer (score 1):

They're like distance/rate/time problems. It boils down to repeated use of the equation Work=Rate*Time.

In this case, $j=(mr)(h)$, where $r$ is the rate of a single worker. Solving for it, we get $r=\frac{j}{mh}$. When $p$ people are hired, the new number of workers is $(m+p)$, so our new rate is $(m+p)r$. Plugging in our expression for $r$, this simplifies to $\frac{(m+p)j}{mh}$

Now we can write the same formula with the new rate and an unknown time $t$, and then solve for $t$. Thus:

$j=(\frac{(m+p)j}{mh})(t)$

We immediately obtain: $t=h\frac{m}{m+p}$.

---

A quicker, but less general method is this: The number of workers increased in the ratio $\frac{m+p}{m}$, so the time they take should decrease by the ratio $\frac{m}{m+p}$, as we just saw.